# Documentation of Hydra Config

Tags: fb-hydra

[Hydra](https://hydra.cc/docs/intro/) provides a way to *dynamically create a hierarchical configuration by composition and override it through config files and the command line*, leveraging [OmegaConf](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io). I look for a recommended way to document the parameters but I could not find (a documented) one. What are best practices for that? Coming from argparse, I like the way of documenting the parameter inline, i.e. close to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question! The answer is: parameter-by-parameter documentation is not yet implemented (as of Hydra v1.1, OmegaConf v2.1).

The future plans are:

- in OmegaConf, expose an API allowing users to attach documentation (and other metadata) to each field of a structured config. See [this open OmegaConf issue](https://github.com/omry/omegaconf/issues/131).
- Once the above is complete, implement a Hydra feature allowing a parameter-specific help messages to be printed based on the parameter's metadata. See [this open Hydra issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/633).

For now, the best we can do is to [customize](https://hydra.cc/docs/configure_hydra/app_help/) the general application help message (i.e. the `--help` command line flag).